# How do I run artisan commands with parameters in route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Running this code gives the expected result

```
Route::get('/make', function(){
 Artisan::call('make:mail',['name'=>'OrderShipped']);
});
```

I how ever want to add markdown to it. `--markdown=emails.orders.shipped`
How do I add the markdown?

Comment: have you tried `Artisan::call('make:mail',['--markdown' => 'emails.orders.shipped']);`

Comment: @djunehor i have tried it but has not worked.

Comment: Did it throw any error? If it did, can you share?

Comment: @djunehor "Not enough arguments (missing: "name").". this is the error that was returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
Artisan::call('make:mail', ['name' => 'OrderShipped', '--markdown' => 'emails.orders.shipped']);
```

I hope it helps.